# Perl XML::Compile::WSDL11 error element Policy not processed at wsp:Policy

Tags: perl, soap, wsdl

when I try to add the WSDL file there is an error:

```
XML::Compile::WSDL11::addWSDL($myWSDL)
```

```
error: element `{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy}Policy' not processed for wsdl:definitions at /*/wsp:Policy

at /perl/site/lib/XML/Compile/Translate/Reader.pm line 590
```

if i remove the policy part in my WSDL file, it works. Is there a workaround?

```
<!--
 Policy for UsernameToken with plaintext password, sent from client to server only 
-->
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="UsernameToken">
<wsp:ExactlyOne>
<wsp:All>
<sp:SupportingTokens>
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:UsernameToken sp:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
<wsp:Policy/>
</sp:UsernameToken>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:SupportingTokens>
</wsp:All>
</wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
</definitions>
```

after removing the policy part everthing works as expected

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.